# Finding SPNE and NE

Tags: game-theory

Given the diagram, find SPNE and NE. Now, NE in my opinion will be (L1,L2) leading to the payoff (1,1) but SPNE by backward induction is coming out to be (R1,R2) leading to (2,2)?

[image]